# cpp operator overload operand position [] vs ==

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

How does `char& operator[]` differ from `bool operator==`? One puts the operand in between `[]`, while the other puts the operand after `==`. How does it know where to put the operand? Is there any trick special for the open and closing brackets?

Comment: Overloading operators does not change the language grammar. `[]` always comes after the thing it applies to. `==` always comes between the two things it applies to. Unary `*` always comes before the thing it applies to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How does it know where to put the operand?

Um. Because the standard says so?

[§11.5.5 Subscripting [over.sub]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.oper#over.sub-1):

> `operator[]` shall be a non-static member function with exactly one parameter. It implements the subscripting syntax
>
> *postfix-expression* [ *expr-or-braced-init-list* ]
>
> Thus, a subscripting expression `x[y]` is interpreted as `x.operator[](y)` for a class object `x` of type `T` if `T​::​operator[](T1)` exists and if the operator is selected as the best match function by the overload resolution mechanism ([over.match.best]).